# Mysql LEFT JOIN GROUP BY LAST Records from each Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I would like to link several tables and have the last records of each entry in the linked table.

E.g.

```
Tabelle Domain

-- ID -- | -- DOMAIN -- | -- DATE --
    1         seite.de      08-09-2020
 
Tabelle Domain Verify

-- ID -- | -- DOMAIN_ID -- | -- IS SSL -- | -- DATE --
    1               1             0            06-09-2020
    2              1              1            07-09-2020
    3              1              1            08-09-2020
 
Tabelle Domain SSL

-- ID -- | -- DOMAIN_ID -- | -- SSL NAME -- | -- DATE --
    1                   1           NOT             06-09-2020
    2                  1            ENCRYPT          07-09-2020
    3                  1            ENCRYPT           08-09-2020

Tabelle Revoked:

-- ID -- | -- DOMAIN_ID -- | -- REVOKED -- | -- DATE --
    1                  1          1           06-09-2020
    2                  1          0           07-09-2020
    3                  1          0           08-09-2020
```

Now he shows me in the domain SSL table that the SSL name is NOT. But wanted to show the latest post where ENCRYPT STANDS from 08.09

```
SELECT

domain.id,

domain_verify.domain_id,
domain_verify.ssl_check

domain_ssl.domain_id,
domain_ssl.ssl_name,

domain_ssl_revoked.domain_id,
domain_ssl_revoked.revoked

FROM domain

LEFT JOIN domain_verify
ON domain_verify.domain_id = domain.id

LEFT JOIN domain_ssl
ON domain_ssl.domain_id = domain_verify.id

LEFT JOIN domain_ssl_revoked
ON domain_ssl_revoked.domain_id = domain_verify.id

GROUP BY domain_verify.id ORDER BY domain_verify.date DESC
```

Comment: Which version of MYSQL and can you show the expected data.

Comment: You should probably learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  Your code shouldn't have executed.  It should error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining by corresponding aggregate queries. Below uses table alias for readability (i.e., reduce all the `domain` references).

```
SELECT d.id
     , v.domain_id AS v_domain_id, v.ssl_check
     , s.domain_id AS s_domain_id, s.ssl_name
     , r.domain_id AS r_domain_id, r.revoked

FROM domain d

LEFT JOIN domain_verify v ON v.domain_id = d.id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT domain_id, MAX(date) as max_date
     FROM domain_verify v
     GROUP BY domain_id) agg_v
  ON  agg_v.domain_id = v.domain_id
  AND agg_v.max_date = v.date

LEFT JOIN domain_ssl s ON s.domain_id = v.id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT domain_id, MAX(date) as max_date
     FROM domain_ssl
     GROUP BY domain_id) agg_s
  ON  agg_s.domain_id = s.domain_id
  AND agg_s.max_date = s.date

LEFT JOIN domain_ssl_revoked r ON r.domain_id = v.id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT domain_id, MAX(date) as max_date
     FROM domain_ssl_revoked
     GROUP BY domain_id) agg_r
  ON  agg_r.domain_id = r.domain_id
  AND agg_r.max_date = r.date

ORDER BY v.date DESC
```

Should you one day support [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) (incorporated in MySQL 8.0+), consider flagging rows with check against maximum date.

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, v_domain_id, ssl_check, ssl_namme, revoked
FROM
   (SELECT d.id
         , v.date, v.domain_id AS v_domain_id, v.ssl_check
         , s.domain_id AS s_domain_id, s.ssl_name
         , r.domain_id AS r_domain_id, r.revoked
         , if(v.date = MAX(v.date) OVER(PARTITION BY v.domain_id), 1, 0) AS latest_v_dt
         , if(s.date = MAX(s.date) OVER(PARTITION BY s.domain_id), 1, 0) AS latest_s_dt
         , if(r.date = MAX(r.date) OVER(PARTITION BY r.domain_id), 1, 0) AS latest_r_dt
    FROM domain d  
    LEFT JOIN domain_verify v 
          ON v.domain_id = d.id AND latest_v_dt = 1   
    LEFT JOIN domain_ssl s
          ON s.domain_id = v.id AND latest_s_dt = 1   
    LEFT JOIN domain_ssl_revoked r
          ON r.domain_id = v.id AND latest_r_dt = 1
   ) sub    
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```